# how to add mulitple data rows in php object

Tags: php, xml

The SOAP API of a payment engine requires multiple RequestParameters such as customeraccountname and customeraccountnummber:

```
<soapenv:Body Id="_body">
 <req:TransactionRequest>
  <req:Currency>EUR</req:Currency>
  <req:Services>
   <req:Service Name="directdebit" Action="Pay" Version="1">
    <req:RequestParameter Name="customeraccountname">Joe Doe</req:RequestParameter>
    <req:RequestParameter Name="customeraccountnumber">123456789</req:RequestParameter>
   </req:Service>
  </req:Services>
 </req:TransactionRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I use the following PHP code to try to achief this:

```
<?php
$TransactionRequest = new Body();
$TransactionRequest->Currency = 'EUR';

$TransactionRequest->Services = new Services();
$TransactionRequest->Services->Service = new Service();
$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->Name= 'directdebit';
$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->Action = 'Pay';
$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->Version = 1;

$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->RequestParameter = new RequestParameter();
$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->RequestParameter->Name = 'customeraccountname';
$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->RequestParameter->_ = 'Joe Doe';

$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->RequestParameter = new RequestParameter();
$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->RequestParameter->Name = 'customeraccountnumber';
$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->RequestParameter->_ = '123456789';


//echo var_dump($TransactionRequest);
print_r($TransactionRequest);

class Body
{
    public $Currency;
    public $Services;
}

class Services
{
    public $Global;
    public $Service;
}

class Service
{
    public $RequestParameter;
    public $Name;
    public $Action;
    public $Version;
}

class RequestParameter
{
    public $_;
    public $Name;
    public $Group;
}
?>
```

The resulting object however doesn't contain the first RequestParameter:

```
Body Object
(
    [Currency] => EUR
    [Services] => Services Object
        (
            [Global] => 
            [Service] => Service Object
                (
                    [RequestParameter] => RequestParameter Object
                        (
                            [_] => 123456789
                            [Name] => customeraccountnumber
                            [Group] => 
                        )
                    [Name] => directdebit
                    [Action] => Pay
                    [Version] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

How could I achief the required result?

Looking forward to your help, Regards Robert

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have overridden the first parameter.
You need to make RequestParameter an array of objects.

```
$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->RequestParameter = new Array();

$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->RequestParameter[0] = new RequestParameter();
$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->RequestParameter[0]->name='customeraccountname';
$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->RequestParameter[0]->_ = 'Jon Doe';

$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->RequestParameter[1] = new RequestParameter();
$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->RequestParameter[1]->name='customeraccountnumber';
$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->RequestParameter[1]->_ = '123456789';
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: This trows an error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ARRAY

Comment: Solved with some additional info from miqrogroove.com/blog

$new_array = array();
$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->RequestParameter =& $need_to_free_up_this_var;
$need_to_free_up_this_var =& $new_array;
unset ($new_array);

$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->RequestParameter[0] = new RequestParameter();
.........
$TransactionRequest->Services->Service->RequestParameter[1]->_ = '123456789';

Comment: @user2556146: Please add that as an answer, link those resources, explain why it works now and what in concrete the "error" was that you got solved. You can then accept that answer. Also using references/variable aliaising does not seem valid to me.